# Cerrar AlertDialog

Tags: android, alertdialog

Abro el dialog y se puede observar que mando llamar ya sea para tomar una foto o para seleccionarla de galeria. El problema esque una ves cargada la foto el AlertDialog sigue abierto, claro que se puede agregar un boton como el de cancelar con un simple `dismiss` pero necesito cerrarlo cuando la actividad de galeria o fotos se cierre. es decir.. ¿como puedo cerrar el Alertdialog desde fuera?

```
private void seleccionarMedio() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    dialog.setTitle("Selecciona una foto");
    dialog.setMessage("Puedes tomar una foto o cargar una antes previamente tomada");
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View login_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vista_foto,null);
    LinearLayout Galeria = (LinearLayout)login_layout.findViewById(R.id.botonGaleria);
    LinearLayout Tomar = (LinearLayout)login_layout.findViewById(R.id.botonTomar);

    dialog.setView(login_layout);
    Galeria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona app de imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);
              //Cerrar dialog en esta parte.

        }
    });

    Tomar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openCamera();
        }
    });


    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: puedes poner como creas el AlertDialog? Porque lo podrías guardar en un objeto y desde ese objeto cerrarlo

Comment: listo he modificado.

Comment: Mira esta pregunta, está bastante relacionada con lo que quieres: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285235/how-to-dismiss-alertdialog-builder

Comment: en el activityforResult podrias colocar un case o un if, de acuerdo al codigo del intent, para cerrarlo, y dejas el dialogo como variable local

Answer (score 2):

El metodo `AlertDialog.Builder#show()` retorna un objeto de tipo `AlertDialog` que tiene el metodo `dismiss()`.

Guarda la referencia del resultado para cerrar el `AlertDialog` fuera del mismo:

```
private AlertDialog _dialog;
private void seleccionarMedio() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    //...

    dialog.setView(login_layout);
    Galeria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona app de imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);

            // verificamos que el objeto no sea null
            if(NombreActividadActual.this._dialog!=null){
                NombreActividadActual.this._dialog.dismiss()
            }

        }
    });

    //...

    _dialog = dialog.show();
}
```